# ros2 topic echo for arrays

Tags: ros2, rostopic-echo

Is there an equivalent to `rostopic echo /predictions/agent[0]/intention` in ros2?

I can use `ros2 topic echo predictions --field agent` successfully, but when I try `--field agent[0]` I get an error `Invalid field 'agent[0]'`